# Change & characters in a xml file

Tags: regex, xml, replace

In an XML file I want to replace the character `&` with `&#x26;` in a specific XML element.

Here the structure of the directories and XML files:
OrderImport
----> 111
----> 112
----> 113
----> 114
----> 115
...

In one folder there are two XML files.

One is called **file_drupal.xml**, the second file is called **fileRDE.xml**.

Structure of the XML file **file_drupal.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<companys>
    <company id="4356722" old_id="972214">
        <producer>text & text continues</producer>
        <date>
            <createdDate>2019-06-28T13:09:25+00:00</createdDate>
            <publishingDate>2012-07-13T00:00:00+00:00</publishingDate>
        </date>
        <workflow>published</workflow>
        <text> Laboriosam, fermentum facilis magnam cras pede incididunt placerat rerum urna ut & eget justo atque? Distinctio? Ipsa sunt tempore? Necessitatibus saepe 
    duis repudiandae wisi reiciendis
       </text>
    </company>
</companys>
```

The `&` character should be replaced by `&#x26;` in the `<producer>` element.

Global in the file **file_drupal.xml** I can do this with the following command:

```
find . -type f -name "file\_drupal\.xml" -exec ex -sc '%s/&/&#x26;/g' -cx {} ';'
```

But I want to replace the `&` character in the file **file_drupal.xml** only in the `<producer>` element.

The `&` character should be replaced in the entire **FolderImport** folder, in all the **file_drupal.xml** files in it.

How can I solve this?

Comment: In the general case, regular expressions are a poor tool for manipulating structured formats; but if the input is restricted, it can work. In particular, can you guarantee that `<producer>....</producer>` always occurs all together on a single line in every file?

Comment: Yes, that is the case

Comment: You called it an XML file but it isn't. It would less confusing to everyone, including yourself, if you called it a non-XML file.The point being that there are lots of tools out there for manipulating XML files, but very few for manipulating non-XML files. And the other point being that you need to be very clear in your dealings with whoever is creating this abomination that if they think they are providing you with XML, they are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If the `</producer>` end tag always occurs on the same line as the `<producer>` start tag, try something like

```sh
perl -pe 's%(.*<producer>)(.*?)(</producer>.*)%
  $a = $1; $b = $2; $c = $3; $b =~ s|&|&x26;|g; "$a$b$c"%ge' OrderImport/*/file_drupal.xml
```

The `-i~` option says to store the original in `file_drupal.xml~` as a backup. Maybe take out the `~` once you are certain that this works correctly.

Demo: https://ideone.com/mohRG5